# JavaScript loop through two arrays

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

There are two arrays:

```
let cats = [];
var biscuits = [];
```

where I am adding elements with .push, for example I'll have:

```
cats = ["Andy", "Bandy", "Candy", "Dandy"]
biscuits = 14;
```

What function to write to have a report on how many biscuits each cat got, considering I will start to feed them from the first cat in the array:

```
Andy got 4 biscuits
Bandy got 4 biscuits
Candy got 3 biscuits
Dandy got 3 biscuits
```

Comment: This is a work order disguised as a question and is therefor too broad. If you'd like help you need to show what you've tried, why it didn't work and ask a specific question about where you ran into trouble. Please review [ask].

Comment: Write complete code please.Like so it's so vagous..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```js
const biscuitsPerCat = (cats, biscuits) => {
  const share = Math.floor(biscuits / cats.length)
  const cutoff = biscuits - cats.length * share
  return cats.reduce((res, cat, idx) => ({...res, [cat]: idx < cutoff ? share + 1 : share}), {})
}

console.log(biscuitsPerCat(["Andy", "Bandy", "Candy", "Dandy"], 14))
```

... which you could then use to format your output?

Answer (score 1):

You could take the power of [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) for the right amount of biscuits.

```js
var cats = ["Andy", "Bandy", "Candy", "Dandy"],
    biscuits = 14;

cats.forEach((v, i, { length }) => 
    console.log(`${v} got ${Math.floor(biscuits / length) + (biscuits % length > i)} biscuits`));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you use that boolean -> int coercion in code maintained by a team?  I know it works, and that it is per spec, but I have a hard time including such things as the degree of required explanation is too high.  I'm curious to know if you have different experiences with it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, actually i have no experience with teams, i am retired.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I see your (always excellent) answers and comments everywhere I turn!